# JS push function to literals

Tags: javascript

In Axel Rauschmayer's book [Exploring ES6](http://exploringjs.com), I've stumbled on this code snippet:

```js
const arr = [];
for (let i=0; i < 3; i++) {
    arr.push(() => i); //1
}
console.log(
  arr.map(x => x()) //2
)
```

Can you explain me how numbers are represented/stored in operations on lines commented as /1 and /2, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Line Comment 1:**

Here you are pushing a `function` into your array. Here you're using an arrow function, so converting this to an anonymous function, you are essentially pushing:

```
function() {
  return i
}
```

into your array.

This function will return the variable `i`. The value of `i` is determined through your for loop. Thus after running your for loop, you have an array of functions which looks (somewhat, but not exactly) like this:

`[function() {retrun 0}, function() {return 1}, function() {return 2}];`

**Line Comment 2:**

Running the `map` method on this array converts each function call to its returned value. It does this by invoking each element/function by doing `x()`. As `x` represents a given function within your array of functions, doing `x()` will thus give you a number.

So, storing the mapped version of this into a variable we get the result of what each function returned:

`[0, 1, 2]`

```js
const arr = [];
for (let i=0; i < 3; i++) {
    arr.push(() => i); //1
}
let res = arr.map(x => x()); //2
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you, man! It wasn't obvious for me that when you push some value to a function it implicitly becomes return value of a function.